# Is 2d space a subset of 3d?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I’m working on some exercises on sets. One of the tasks asked if $R^2 \subseteq R^3$

So talking in terms of sets, it’s false (which is confirmed by the book), since $R^2$ is a set of pairs and $R^3$ is a set of triplets.

When I’m thinking in a bit more natural way, I see $R^3$ as an infinite stack of $R^2$. I’m not sure if I can write it like that, but to some extent I feel like I could define it as $R^3 = \{(R^2, z) : z \in R\}$

I can’t seem to see the logical error in the latter. Any help?

Comment: The problem is that being a subset is something that is true in only one way. As you have noticed, there are a lot of subsets of $\mathbb R^3$ that "look like" $\mathbb R^2.$ So whatever the relationship is between $\mathbb R^2$ and $\mathbb R^3,$ it is not a subset relationship. There is no way to prefer one of these subsets.

Comment: What you've written for $R^3$ is not quite right. But note there is a natural bijection between $\{\,(x,y,z)\mid x,y,z\in R\,\}$ and $\{\,((x,y),z)\mid x,y,z\in R\,\}$.

Comment: @blargoner Often, $X^n$ is first defined inductively on $n.$ Then $\mathbb R^3$ is literally equal to $\mathbb R^2\times\mathbb R.$ But it all depends on definitions.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I'm well aware of that, thanks. If that's the OP's definition he can take the bijection to be the identity. :)

Comment: It's good that this has tripped you up, as it's quite a technical question which doesn't necessarily have a straightforward answer in more advanced set theory (it's "implementation-dependent"). In much the same way, you may have seen that there are some technicalities about whether it's true that $\Bbb Z \subseteq \Bbb R$, and so on. I suspect the answer that's intended here is "no, because the elements are different types of objects". It's not a great question - in practice it wouldn't come up, as we mostly care about the subset relation in the context of some fixed, shared universe.

Comment: Some exercises ... presumably, where this was asked, there were previously given precise definitions for $R^2$ and $R^3$.  That would be the only  way this could be answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your difficulty with this stems from the fact that while philosophers have forced set theory on us mathematicians as "the foundations of mathematics", it isn't really the foundation for mathematics as practiced.

Equality between sets with structure (e.g. real vector spaces, normed real vector spaces, topological manifolds, smooth manifolds,...) is usually not an interesting notion.  Isomorphism (the existence of a structure preserving map with a structure preserving inverse) is usually the interesting notion, and of course, ${\mathbb R}^2$ is isomorphic as a real vector space (or a normed real vector space, or a topological manifold, or a smooth manifold) to a subset of ${\mathbb R}^3$ with the structure induce by restriction, for the first two structures in my list you have to pick $z=0$ in your picture of a stack of ${\mathbb R}^2$'s, while for the last two structures in my list, any $z$ will do.

(As an aside, we call isomorphism of topological spaces, including manifolds, "homeomorphism", and of smooth spaces, including smooth manifolds, "diffeomorphism", but the general principle applies to the special cases.)